# Finding Power set of a Set

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, set

[Homework Assignment]

We have to find the power set of a given set using Java or C++. The set will be accepted in the form of an array of any size and I need to display the elements of the power set of that set. Note that the only concepts to use are arrays, loops and functions (recursive and iterative).

I need someone to point me in the right direction regarding the logic I can apply.
Please help.

PS : Power set of a set A is the set of all subsets of set A
Eg. A = { a, b, c}
    Power Set of A = {{},{a},{b},{c},{a,b},{b,c},{a,c},{a,b,c}}

---

Edit:

**Thanks a lot to "wy" and "MrSmith42"!** I have written my program using the logic they have given. Now I am trying to optimize it. Note that I am new to Java and find it slightly uncomfortable due to its newness.

Here's my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PowerSet {

    //Function to increment binary string...

    static String incr_bin (String binary){
        char bin[] = new char[100];
        int size_bin, i;
        size_bin = binary.length();
        bin = binary.toCharArray(); 
        bin[size_bin-1]++;
        for(i=size_bin-1; i>=0; i--){
            if (i != 0){
                if(bin[i] > '1'){
                    bin[i]='0';
                    bin[i-1]++;
                }
            }
        }
        if (bin[0]>'1'){
            for(i=0;i<size_bin;i++){
                bin[i]='0';
            }
        }
        binary = new String (bin);
        return binary;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Declarations

        Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
        int a[] = new int [100];
        int size_a, i, count=0;

        String binary;

        //Input

        System.out.println("Enter the number of elements in A : ");
        size_a = in.nextInt();
        char bin[] = new char [size_a];
        System.out.println("Enter the elements in A : ");
        for(i=0; i<size_a; i++){
            a[i] = in.nextInt();
            bin[i] = '0';
        }
        binary = new String(bin);

        //Calculating and Setting up subsets
        System.out.println("MEMBERS OF POWER SET :");
        do{
            System.out.print("\n{.");
            count = 0;
            binary = incr_bin(binary);
            bin = binary.toCharArray();
            for(i=0; i<size_a; i++){
                if (bin[i] == '0') count++;
                if (bin[i] == '1') System.out.print(a[i] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println("}");
        }while(count!=size_a);      
    }
}
```

Comment: The **only** way to learn how to code is by trying to code. Please try and come back with specific question.

Comment: I know how to code, I am just stuck up with how to handle so many arrays and manipulate them simultaneously.

Comment: @whoAmI Did you read the question? ***I need someone to point me in the right direction regarding the logic I can apply*** I don't see code requests in this question

Comment: @BackSlash learning to code includes knowing what way to go (or at least what to ask). I don't think that this question should be answered until it gets more specific.

Comment: @whoAmI : I have edited my question. I need logic, not code. Please help if you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To output the Power Set,there are three ways in "14.5 Generating Subsets", The Alogrithm Design Manual,and I have tried all of them with only array,loop and functions. But there will be no code.Here are short paragraphs about them:

> 1.**Lexicographic order** – Lexicographic order means sorted order, and is
> often the most natural way to generate combinatorial objects. The
> eight subsets of {1, 2, 3} in lexicographic order are {} , {1}, {1,
> 2}, {1, 2, 3}, {1, 3}, {2}, {2, 3}, and {3}. But it is surprisingly
> difficult to generate subsets in lexicographic order. **Unless you have
> a compelling reason to do so, don’t bother.**
>
> 2.**Gray Code** – A particularly interesting and useful subset sequence is   the  minimum change order, wherein adjacent subsets differ by the
> insertion or deletion of exactly one element. Such an ordering, called
> a Gray code. Generating subsets in Gray code order can be very fast,
> because there is a nice recursive construction. Construct a Gray code
> of n − 1 elements G<sub>n−1</sub>  Reverse a > second copy of G<sub>n−1</sub> and add n to
> each subset in this copy. Then  concatenate them together to create G<sub>n</sub> .
> **Further, since only one element changes between subsets, exhaustive
> search algorithms built on Gray codes can be quite efficient.**
>
> 3.**Binary counting**– **The simplest approach** to subset-generation problems is based on the observation that any subset S' is defined by
> the items of that S are in S'. We can represent S' by a binary string
> ofn bits, where bit i is 1iffthe ith element of S is in S'. This
> defines a bijection between the 2<sup>n</sup> binary strings of length
> n,and the 2<sup>n</sup> subsets of n items. For n = 3, binary counting
> generates subsets in the following order: {} , {3}, {2}, {2,3}, {1},
> {1,3}, {1,2}, {1,2,3}. This binary representation is the key to
> solving all subset generation problems. To generate all subsets in
> order, simply count from 0 to 2<sup>n-1</sup>. For each integer,
> successively mask off each of the bits and compose a subset of exactly
> the items corresponding to 1 bits. To generate the next or previous
> subset, increment or decrement the integer by one.Unranking a subset
> is ex-actly the masking procedure, while ranking constructs a binary
> number with 1’s corresponding to items in S and then converts this
> binary number to an integer.

if you want an easy one, just Binary Counting is enough, it can be recurrence implement such as backtracking  or a specific one.If you have done it and want more challenge,you can code a Gray Code one. You can learn how to generate Gray Code on its wiki page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code#Genetic_algorithms).

Comment: Brilliantly explained. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 9):

You can map every element of the power set to a binary number with as much bits as the size of your set.

e.g.

```
     A = { a, b, c} 
     binary number  => resulting subset
     000            => {     }  // no 'a',  no 'b', no 'c'
     001            => {    c}
     010            => {  b  }
     011            => {  b,c}
     100            => {a    }
     101            => {a,  c}
     110            => {a,b  }
     111            => {a,b,c}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was what I was kind of looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the implementation in java. This uses the logic explained above using bits.

```
/**
 * Prints all subsets of a list
 * @param list
 */
public static void printSubsets(List<Integer> list) {
    int max = (int)Math.pow(2, list.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        // Convert int to bitset
        BitSet bs = getConvertedBitSet(i, list.size());

        // Use bitset to print the subset
        printSubset(bs, list);
    }
}

/**
 * Helper function for {@link org.vikastaneja.companies.Expedia#printSubsets(java.util.List)}<br/>
 * This function prints the subsets for the bits that are set in bitset
 * @param bs
 * @param list
 */
private static void printSubset(BitSet bs, List<Integer> list) {
    if (list == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Set is empty");
    }

    System.out.print("{ ");
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size();i++) {
        if (bs.get(i)) {
            System.out.print(list.get(i) + " ");
        }
    }

    System.out.print("}");

    System.out.println();
}

/**
 * Helper function for {@link org.vikastaneja.companies.Expedia#printSubsets(java.util.List)}<br/>
 * This function converts an integer to the bitset
 * @param value
 * @param size
 * @return
 */
private static BitSet getConvertedBitSet(int value, int size) {
    BitSet bits = new BitSet(size);
    bits.set(0, size - 1, false);
    int index = 0;
    while (value != 0) {
        if (value % 2 != 0) {
            bits.set(index);
        }
        ++index;
        value = value >>> 1;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Binary counting using increment/decrement is fine until your universal set has more elements than your biggest integral type has bits.  However, The rule of succession is quite simple.  Given subset S_k represented as a bit vector, you generate S_{k+1} as follows:

```
for i in 0..len(s):
  if s[i]:
    s[i] = 0
  else:
    s[i] = 1
    break
```

Starting with [000], its easy to see this generates [100],[010],[110],[001],...[111].  To generate all of them, wrap the above in a loop and keep track of cardinality of the subset, adding or subtracting 1 as you set bits to 1 or 0.  Your last subset will have cardinality n.